# Team Foundation Server 2010 Reinstall on existing databases

Tags: tfs

I accidentally uninstalled TFS 2010 from server but Databases remain. Can I reinstall with out disturbing the databases or do I need to use a back up to restore after TFS 2010 is installed?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to reinstall TFS and just point it at the database during configuration. When you reinstall, you should be able to choose the "Application Tier Only" configuration option, which will ask you to point it to the correct databases.

I'd recommend backing up your TFS databases first as a precaution, but you should be doing that already!

Comment: thanks for the advice. As being a TFS newbie the information you gave me saved hours of work!